# MySQL BIGINT datatype for t_stamp

Tags: mysql

I am not familiar with this t_stamp datatype nor how to read it. I have a table where they created a t_stamp using BIGINT datatype. On the table it reads the following: 1491419796120
I have no idea what it means, please help.

Thanks!

Comment: It's the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, like the function `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` returns.

Comment: Actually, it looks like it also includes milliseconds, because it's 13 digits long.

Comment: [This](http://www.convert-unix-time.com/?t=1491516447) might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for guidance Barmar, I'm going to look into it.

Comment: If you use the real timestamp datatype, it will be displayed as a date / time instead of just an impossible number.